# PHP Error Call to undefined function, how to give a method data to use

Tags: php, csv, phpexcel

I am building a script that takes every xls file from the /uploads folder and converts it to CSV.

But, I am having this error:

> **Fatal error:**
>   Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function convertXLStoCSV() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Technocripa-php\scandir.php:46 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Technocripa-php\scandir.php on line 46

Here is the code:

```
$dir = "uploads/*";
foreach(glob($dir) as $file)
{
    if(!is_dir($file)) { echo basename($file)."\n";}
    //--------------------------

    $nameAsString = (string)$file;

    require_once('Classes/PHPExcel.php');

    $inputfilename = $nameAsString;
    $outputfilename = 'convert.csv';

    //Usage:
    convertXLStoCSV($inputfilename, $outputfilename);

    function convertXLStoCSV($infile, $outfile)
    {
        $fileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($infile);
        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($fileType);

        $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($infile);

        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'CSV');
        $objWriter->save($outfile);
    }
}
```

I think the error comes from wrong variable usage, but I really can't find a way to fix this. All I want to is store the name of te file in the uploads/ folder in a variable and use it throughout my script.

Here's the program without the LOOP, it works without any errors. Maybe it helps to understand better.

```
require_once('Classes/PHPExcel.php');

  $inputfilename = 'test2.xls';
  $outputfilename = 'convert.csv';

  //Usage:
  convertXLStoCSV($inputfilename, $outputfilename);

  function convertXLStoCSV($infile, $outfile)
  {
      $fileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($infile);
      $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($fileType);

      $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
      $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($infile);

      $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'CSV');
      $objWriter->save($outfile);
  }
```

Comment: you're calling the function before it's being created...

Comment: You don't need to redefine the function on every loop iteration, just define it once for the entire script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the function outside of `foreach` and call it inside like below:

```
function convertXLStoCSV($infile, $outfile)
{
    $fileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($infile);
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($fileType);

    $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($infile);

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'CSV');
    $objWriter->save($outfile);
}

$dir = "uploads/*";
foreach(glob($dir) as $file)
{
    if(!is_dir($file)) { echo basename($file)."\n";}
    //--------------------------

    $nameAsString = (string)$file;

    require_once('Classes/PHPExcel.php');

    $inputfilename = $nameAsString;
    $outputfilename = 'convert.csv';

    //Usage:
    convertXLStoCSV($inputfilename, $outputfilename);


}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    function convertXLStoCSV($infile, $outfile)
    {
        $fileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($infile);
        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($fileType);

        $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($infile);

        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'CSV');
        $objWriter->save($outfile);
    }

convertXLStoCSV($inputfilename, $outputfilename);
```

declare the function before using it